# Problem Patching SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, configuration-wizard

I have a single server sharepoint 2010 farm (Database-SQL server 2008 R2, SharePoint server 2010 both installed on the same server)

This morning, we started patching the SP 2010 by installing the SP 2010 service pack 2 first and then the June 2017 CU. All went well.

Now time to run the SharePoint Products Configuration wizard to upgrade the farm. Running the wizard throws up an error

> Internet information services not installed. You must have Internet
>   information services installed to run the SharePoint Products
>   Configuration wizard

I opened IIS manager and there Internet information services is installed and running!

I try to open SharePoint Central Admin and it opens.

Still, i am not able to run the SharePoint Products Configuration wizard because of the error.

I will appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check this? http://relationaldevelopment.com/post/SharePoint-2010-Configuration-Wizard-Fails-with-IIS-not-Installed.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please have a look to your Windows Services console.
- Maybe the "IIS Admin Service" has startup type "Disabled". Set it to automatic and start the service.
- Just to make sure: Perform an IISRESET
- Start Products Configuration Wizard again

Comment: I guess `IISRESET` should work..

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I tried starting the IIS Admin service, it failed to start. Tried IISRESET, it failed. Then I followed the instructions here https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24546925/IIS-Admin-Service-will-not-start.html . That solved the IISRESET and IIS Admin Service issues. then I ran the configuration wizard again. this time it succeeded. Thanks alot.